# How to format Scrapy exports

Tags: python, scrapy

I currently store my scraped data in an item to export in .csv format:

```
item = HobbyItem()
item['name'] = user.getName()
item['hobbies'] = user.getHobbies()
```

The item is declared as follows:

```
name = scrapy.Field()
hobbies = scrapy.Field()
```

This results in a csv format as follows:

```
name,hobbies
Tim, [['tennis'],['squash'],['music']]
Bob, [['rugby'],['polo']]
```

What I actually want is this:

```
name,hobbies
Tim, 'tennis'
Tim, 'squash'
Tim, 'music'
Bob, 'rugby'
Bob, 'polo'
```

Does anybody know how I can modify the output to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show the definition of HobbyItem and field definitions?

Comment: Hi @notionquest. I have updated as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You did not let enough code or explanation for me to be sure that this will work in your particular code but

Try :

```
for element in user.getHobbies():
    item['name'] = user.getName()
    item['hobbies'] = element[0]
```

This will create 1 element per hobby, using getName multiple times

Answer (score 0):

```
name = user.getName()
for hobby in user.getHobbies():
    if hobby:
        item = HobbyItem()
        item['name'] = name
        item['hobbies'] = hobby[0]
        yield item
```